# Cannot connect to Windows Server 2008 R2 via http, https works

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, http, packetloss

I've been having a problem with my WS2008R2 server ever since I started IIS7 for the first time. I've been managing to work around it so far, because https access works normally. http, however, has never worked right. The server simply seems to randomly drop packets via http.

I've tried multiple ports and http servers, but all of them exhibit exact same behaviour. The connection takes extremely long and usually times out.

This hold true only for external network (the server acts as a NAT router with two network cards), however, trying to access from internal network works normally. Even attempting to access it from within the network via external IP will yield no result.

I'm guessing it has to do with NAT (although all the ports are correctly routed and this only happens with http), as the packets don't even reach :8000 if I listen to the interface with Wireshark.

Follows the Wireshark capture of the traffic, as seen from the *internal* network card when trying to access the resource through external IP: [TCPFail](https://erevar.net/se/tcpfail.pcap)

Wireshark capture of the successful access, if using the internal IP: [TCPSuccess](https://erevar.net/se/tcpsuccess.pcap)

Duly note how both of those links need to use https to function. To reproduce the problem, feel free to try to access them via http.

Comment: A few things off the top of my head...  Can you telnet to port 80 from various remote boxes?  Are you sure DNS is configured correctly?  Assuming that your server is dual homed, are you sure the routing is configured correctly?

Comment: Everything else works, this server has been operational for months now. DNS resolves for everything, all other protocols are routed correctly. Telnet doesn't work, for internal *or* external IPs, for HTTP servers on any port.